.net Blazor Starter from staticwebdev breakpoint are not being hit
I can put breakpoints in the code, but when i run the app none of the breakpoints are getting hit, and I already did some test print debugging to make sure the line where the breakpoint is is actually being run.
I cloned the .net Blazor Stater project for staticwebdev from
https://github.com/staticwebdev/blazor-starter
for this tutorial
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/deploy-blazor
I upgraded the project from .net 6 to .net 8 using the upgrade wizard in visual studio, so i dont know if maybe something went wrong there. I am also using chrome for the browser, but have tried firefox and edge.
My project .dll does not show up in the debug modules list in visual studio

Have you build the project in debug mode? Besides, I suggest you could firstly create a new blazor 8 server-side project to test if the breakpoint will work or not.

yes the project is in debug mode, ive created a new server-side and it works there. But this template is a WASM template

How about the blazor server app?
